# Determine the Cell of a Table Layout Panel Controls are Contained in

Tags: vb.net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am working on a project in VB.Net, and am using a Table Layout Panel to allow for multiple windows to be open side by side with one another.

The issue I am dealing with right now is figuring out exactly which Column of the Table Layout Panel components are placed in at run time.

For example, let's say I have two Windows open, with 3 Columns.  So there are controls in Columns 1 & 2, and Column 3 is empty.  If I close the Window in Column 1, I want to detect the Column it was in, so that I can shift the Window in Column 2 over to Column 1.  I'm trying to do this so I can resize the windows based on how many windows are being opened side by side.

However I can't seem to find a way to determine exactly while Column is the 'parent' Column.  The parent container is the Table Layout Panel itself, but I don't know how to get the information I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can determine the position of a child control inside a [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) using its [GetPositionFromControl()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method, which will return a [TableLayoutPanelCellPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanelcellposition(v=vs.110).aspx) structure, identifying the `Column` and `Row` of the cell that a control is occupying:

```
Dim Position As TableLayoutPanelCellPosition = 
                TableLayoutPanel1.GetPositionFromControl([ControlName])
```

`Position` reports `Position.Column` and `Position.Row` as Integer values.

You can also detemine which child control is occupying a specified position, using the [GetControlFromPosition()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method:

```
Dim MyControl As Control = TableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(0, 0)
```