# How would one go about resizing controls in relation to the window that contains them?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How would one go about resizing controls in relation to the window that contains them? I'd like to do this in order to to have the control take up a particular amount of the screen, regardless of whether the window is maximised, and independent of monitor resolution.

I have tried setting control.Width as equal to a multiple of Me.ParentForm.Width and done the same for height. I'm unsure of how to properly access the properties of the form/window in order to resize controls in relation to it. I also tried to alter the .Left property in the same way to set the relative position of the control.

```
    Display.Width = Me.ParentForm.Width * 0.25
    Display.Top = 0
    Display.Left = Me.ParentForm.Width - Me.Width
```

The code was intended to make the control take up the entire top-right quadrant of the window, whether it was maximised or not. However, I instead got an exception saying that Me.ParentForm.Width had no value.

This is the exception message:

> "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.'
>
> System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.ParentForm.get returned
>   Nothing."

Comment: Sadly this is not really easy to accomplish in WinForms. This is one of the many reasons behind the MS decision to move its desktop efforts towards WPF and later to UWP

Comment: Look at the anchor and dock.

Comment: ...And see the [TableLayoutPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/tablelayoutpanel-control-overview) for the rest. This container can resize the controls it hosts. Not all controls *like* it, use anchors for them. Dock those that need to always occupy a specific position along the sides of the Form or inside other containers.

Comment: @Jimi The control I'm using is a custom class which inherits PictureBox. Would this cooperate with TableLayoutPanel? If not, is there something I could make the class inherit in order to make it cooperate?

Comment: A PictureBox will love it :) You'll have no problems with that control, it's born and trained for this :). You may have some discussions with TextBox, ProgressBar and MonthCalendar (this one really hates it). Sometimes a ListBox needs to be tamed (it tries to size itself without any other conderation for the context).

Comment: Note that you can place a `TableLayoutPanel` inside the cells of another, to have more control on the overall layout. Or to provide some [Masonry](https://www.google.it/search?q=masonry+grid+gallery&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwirpdqu2_zfAhUJsKQKHd1KB0AQsAR6BAgEEAE&biw=1504&bih=859) effect.

Comment: Thanks for your help @Jimi :) . Before I go, if I create many controls purely in code (as opposed to the design section) , how do I assign each into a cell of the TableLayoutPanel?

Comment: [Determine the Cell of a Table Layout Panel Controls are Contained in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414129/7444103). Follow the links in that answer to the MSDN Docs and also see: [TableLayoutPanel.SetCellPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setcellposition) and friends.

Comment: Adding controls to a `TableLayoutPanel` is generally no different than for any other container.  You just call the `Controls.Add` method and the child control is added to the first available cell.  You only have to do something extra if you want the control in a specific cell.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks for the suggestion. When you say "the first available cell", what do you mean? Is this determined by rows first and then columns or vice versa?

Comment: The exact behaviour is determined by the `GrowStyle` property. Note that you can specify a row and/or column index when you call `Add` or you can accept the default behaviour.