# How to access each field in a Winform TableLayoutPanel in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` in `Winforms`, each field contains exactly one label. I now need to get the row/colum and also what is in that field.

f.E: I have to check if the lables in the first row all have the same text.

How can I do  that?

Comment: [Determine the Cell of a Table Layout Panel Controls are Contained in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50414129/7444103) (VB.Net code, exactly the same in C# of course). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666527/7444103) (implemented, in C# this time)

Comment: Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565075/7444103), a little more complex, but you can find a couple of methods that may come in handy (how to remove a Row from a TLP without generating layout *discrepancies*). Also described more in depth here: [Remove Row inside TableLayoutPanel makes a layout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55225457/7444103).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have to check if the lables in the first row all have the same text.

Use [TableLayoutPanel.GetControlFromPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition?view=netcore-3.1) in a loop...something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool matching = RowMatches(0);
    Console.WriteLine(matching);
}

private bool RowMatches(int row)
{
    string value = null;
    for(int col=0; col<tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount; col++)
    {
        Label lbl = (Label)tableLayoutPanel1.GetControlFromPosition(col, row);
        if (value == null)
        {
            value = lbl.Text;
        }
        else if (lbl.Text != value)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```